# Setting the same random value to a group of rows

Tags: mysql

I need to populate a new column, `Column2`, with random values.

All rows with matching values in `Column1` should have the same random value.

My approach was to perform a self-join on the first column and then assign the value generated by `RAND()` to `Column2`.

```sql
UPDATE table AS t
   JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Column1 FROM table) t1
   ON t.Column1 = t1.Column1
SET Column2 = RAND()
```

The expected result is something like:

```
Column1 | Column2
--------+--------
alpha   | 0.766 
alpha   | 0.766
beta    | 0.234
```

But the actual result is:

```
Column1 | Column2
--------+--------
alpha   | 0.766 
alpha   | 0.329
beta    | 0.234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try generating the random value for each `Column1` group inside the subquery:

```
UPDATE table AS t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Column1, RAND() rnd
    FROM table
    WHERE 1 = 1
) t1
    ON t.Column1 = t1.Column1
SET Column2 = t1.rnd;
```

This should, at the very least, get around the current problem you are having of multiple records belonging to the same `Column1` value having different `Col2` values being assigned.  I added the `WHERE 1 = 1` clause to the subquery just in case MySQL tries to be smart and cache the result from `RAND()`, to reuse it.